# How can I hover only content of span?

Tags: css

Today, I am comming with a problem from work. First of all, the code was created some time ago and I have to correct it now. Of course I've made the [sandbox](https://codepen.io/marekzegarek/pen/dyXgVQQ) easier to avoid unnecessary styles.

```
<div>
  <a id="perfect" href="https://css-tricks.com/">
    <span class="perfect">
      <p>Perfect</p>
    </span>
    <span class="maker">Solution</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="https://css-tricks.com/">
    <span class="problem">Problem</span>
    <span class="maker">Makes me cry</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="https://css-tricks.com/">
    <span class="problem">Problem</span>
    <span class="maker">Makes me cry</span>
  </a>
</div>

div {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.problem {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 10px 0;
}

.maker {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 10px 0;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

I have three tile there. First of all works what I expect, but I would like to receive the same result on the second and third tile without paragraph.

The clue is that red color appears, if I put a mouse on random place above right content. I mean all span called "problem" is on hover.

How to ensure a similar behaviour like in first tile on the others without using paragraph? Do you have some idea?

I've tried to do that using margin, but it was wrong.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] to your question.  Otherwise it may take a while to get you the right help/answer

Comment: The behavior on all three tiles is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into your stylesheets:

```
div > a > span:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

Your issue is that your applying `padding: 30px 10px 0;` to span. The link is applying itself to the entire span with its padding.

I removed padding on your span and instead applied it to the div. - You can now adjust the padding on the div instead of the span.

Additionally, I moved the `#perfect` id to the first div because it had a different background-color.

```css
div {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 30px 10px 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.problem {
  display: block;
}

.problem:hover {
  color: red;
}

.maker {
  display: block;
}

p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p:hover {
  color: red;
}

.perfect {
  display: block;
}

#perfect {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="perfect">
      <a href="https://css-tricks.com/">
        <span class="perfect">
          <p>Perfect</p>
        </span>
        <span class="maker">Solution</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="https://css-tricks.com/">
        <span class="problem">Problem</span>
        <span class="maker">Makes me cry</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a href="https://css-tricks.com/">
        <span class="problem">Problem</span>
        <span class="maker">Makes me cry</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's the point. Padding still exists :( and I have no idea how make it right.

Comment: See the updated code, I removed the padding from your spans and added the padding to div instead. I also moved the `#perfect` id to the first div instead of the `<a>`

Comment: I got the solution :) I've just placed margin instead of padding.

Comment: Great, that works too! - If I helped at all, feel free to upvote. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the display for the .problem from 'block' to 'inline-block', change the padding-top to 0 and give a margin-top of 30px

```
.problem {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px 10px 0;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.problem:hover {
color: red;
}
```